# このprintが機能しない理由はなんですか？

Tags: python

例えば `m = print(l[u+1:len(l)]+l[0:u+1])` とおいて `print(m)` すれば期待通りの動作を得られますが、以下のコードでは動かない理由がわかりません。

期待する結果:
`output: 2341 3412 4123`

実際の結果:
何も出力されません。

**対象のコード:**

```
l = '1234'
for u in range(len(l)-1):
    print(l[u+1:len(l)]+l[0:u+1])
```

Comment: 環境の問題では？　当方の環境（macOS）では問題なく出力されます。

Comment: 当方の環境では出力されました。質問者さんはどのような環境で質問のコードを実行されましたか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。windows11 でVSCを使っております。確かにこちらの環境の問題カモしれません。もう少し触ってみます

Comment: Windows11 + VSCode1.85 で問題ないです。

Comment: 逆に`m = print(l[u+1:len(l)]+l[0:u+1])`としても`print()`の戻り値は`None`だけなので、その後に`print(m)`しても途中の処理結果が表示された後に更に`None`が表示されるだけです。[Return value of print statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34836196/9014308) 何か表示内容がバッファリングやペンディングされたりして即時に表示されていないだけでは？ [Python 3 で標準出力のブロックバッファリングを止める方法](https://qiita.com/bmtsstl/items/8b6ef88d40a6846ea1e3) それから`VSC`とはVisual Studio Communityでしょうか、あるいはVisual Studio Codeでしょうか？ それらの作業環境やスクリプトを`実行`する際に行っている手順や、状況や`出力`を確認する手段や手順は何かといったことも質問記事を編集して追記してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

他の回答にある通り、`m = print(l[u+1:len(l)]+l[0:u+1])`とおいて`print(m)`すると期待通りの動作を**得られません**。

```
l = '1234'
for u in range(len(l)-1):
    m = print(l[u+1:len(l)]+l[0:u+1])
    print(m)
```

**実行結果**

```
2341
None
3412
None
4123
None
```

対象**以外**のコードで`print`関数を再定義するなどの小細工はされていないでしょうか。
他のコードを記述せず、単純に`print("output: 2341 3412 4123")`だけのコードを実行するとうまく動作するならば、他の部分に原因がありそうです。

その場合は質問にソースコード全文を追記するか、単体実行で再現可能なソースコードへ書き換えてください。
詳しくは[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)をご参照ください。

ちなみに下記のように[`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch)を使用してオーバーロード実装することで、ご質問にある環境を再現することができます。

```
from functools import singledispatch
import sys

started = False

@singledispatch
def print(s: str) -> int:
    return int(s)

@print.register
def _(i: int) -> None:
    global started
    if not started:
        sys.stdout.write("output: ")
        started = True
    sys.stdout.write(str(i)+" ")

l = '1234'
for u in range(len(l)-1):
    #print(l[u+1:len(l)]+l[0:u+1])  # この行を有効にして下の2行を削除すると何も出力されない
    m = print(l[u+1:len(l)]+l[0:u+1])
    print(m)
```

**実行結果**

```
output: 2341 3412 4123
```

**参考資料**

- [【Python】引数が異なる関数を定義する方法【オーバーロード】](https://yumarublog.com/python/overload/)

Answer (score 1):

他の回答にもあるように, `print`関数を再定義するなどが原因と思います

(「期待する結果」とは多少異なるが)
Colabでの確認 (Jupyterでも確認可能)

```py
def print(v):
    return f'output: {v}'

# ループ内なので, 結果は出力されない
for n in 10,20,30:
    print(n)

# トップレベルで, セルの最後の演算なので, 出力される
m = print('hello')
print(m)
# output: output: hello
```

上記が原因であれば, 以下のように削除で解決するかも？

```py
del print
```

Answer (score 0):

pythonの組み込み関数である`print()`の解説は以下にあります。
[print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None, flush=False)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#print)

---

対象のコードとして書かれたものを、それだけで実行すると以下のような結果になります。

```
2341
3412
4123
```

今のコードでは`output:`は出力されないし、forループで繰り返されるprint出力はそれぞれ改行コードが付いて3行になります。

---

そのため厳密に期待する出力結果と同じものを得るためには以下のようにする必要があります。
(まあコンソール/コマンドプロンプト等で実行する場合`, flush=False`の部分は有っても無くても変わらないですが)

```
print('output:', end='', flush=False)
l = '1234'
for u in range(len(l)-1):
    print((' ' +(l[u+1:len(l)]+l[0:u+1])), end='', flush=False)

print('')
```

---

コメントに書いたり紹介したように、何かデフォルト的な環境や動作では無い状況が発生しているように見えます。

何か表示内容がバッファリングやペンディングされたりして即時に表示されていないだけでは？
[Python 3 で標準出力のブロックバッファリングを止める方法](https://qiita.com/bmtsstl/items/8b6ef88d40a6846ea1e3)

逆に`m = print(l[u+1:len(l)]+l[0:u+1])`としても`print()`の戻り値は`None`だけなので、その後に`print(m)`しても途中の処理結果(上記最初の実行結果の内容)が表示された後に更に`None`が表示されるだけです。
[Return value of print statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34836196/9014308)

Comment: `flush=False` にはどのような意図が有りますか？

Comment: @mjy さん、仕様説明の記事に書かれていたので、デフォルト動作ではありますがコピーして記述しました。かっこ書きしたとおり、この程度のスクリプトの処理では動作には差が無いでしょう。

Comment: なるほど。
その場合、「コンソール/コマンドプロンプト等で実行する場合, flush=Falseの部分は有っても無くても変わらない」というのは、やや不正確と思います。
どのような場合でも、変らないのではないでしょうか。
それとも、デフォルト値をあえて書くことで動作が変わるケースが有りますか？

Comment: @mjy さん、たまたま書く気になっただけで、特に何か変わることは思いつきません。が、デバッガを介して動かすとか、質問のコードではなくもっと多数の処理があるプログラムの一部で間に間隔を置きながらprintする等の状況とかならば(動作の明確化の説明的な)何か違いが出てくるかもしれませんね。print文の依頼データに改行コード等の表示の区切りとなる何かが含まれるまで出力が遅れる場合があるか、flush=Trueでprint文が実行されたときにすぐに表示される、といった違いですので処理するデータの長さや時間が短かったりすると分からなかったりします。シリアルポート等を介して通信する場合などだと使い方によってはデータが届かないとかタイミングズレが発生したりしますが、まあ質問には関係無いですからね。

Comment: もしかしたら話が噛み合っていないかも知れません。
念のため確認ですが、「`flush=False` の部分は有っても無くても」というのは「`flash=False` でも、`flash=True` でも」という意味だったりしますか？

Comment: 記事本文を書いた時には表面上そういう考えはありませんでした(なので「たまたま書く気に...思いつきません。」が最初の答えです)が、@mjy さんとのコメントやりとりでそう言えば指定を変えた場合には少し変わるかも？ということを内心で意識していたのかもと気付きました。